# php string in a string with double and single quotes as 1 string

Tags: php, arrays, string

Hello, I am trying to make a array in php that looks like this:

```
$array= array("test"2"", "'test"2"'");
```

Of course this doesn't work because of the two strings, but is there a way in php to get is to ignore all quotes in such a string so it sees it as a valid string? The problem being that I need the quotes in my string and it are double quotes and single quotes.

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the quick response! I was wondering if there is a way of doing this with code? I have a huge string to do this with?

```
$array= array("test\"2\"", "'test\"2\"'");
```

Comment: If you need to perform this escaping programmatically, where are you pulling these values from?  If you are writing them by hand, then you you should be manually escaping them.  If they are coming from somewhere else, they are probably already escaped or you would have an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape quotes in strings.

```
$array= array("test\"2\"", "'test\"2\"'");
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I was wondering if there is a way of doing this with code? I have a huge string to do this with?

Comment: Post this in your question

Answer (score 1):

If you write text in double quotes, you have to escape it inside text using `\`.

```
$array = array("test\"2\"", "'test\"2\"'");
```

If you write text in single quotes, you have to escape single quotes same way

```
$array = array('test"2"', '\'test"2"\'');
```

Answer (score 1):

If your array `$array= array("test\"2\"", "'test\"2\"'");` is build using a loop then simply use PHP function addslashes() that will escape the redundant qotations.

```
$strings = array('abc"def', "efg'hij");

foreach($strings as $str){
  echo  addslashes($str) .PHP_EOL;
}
```

https://eval.in/914320